# How to get id of the inserted entity when using ViewModel?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-room, android-viewmodel

**The root problem: I want to set the id of [Entity A] in foreign key of [Entity B] but id of [Entity A] is not available until inserted in the database (because it is autogenerated by the DBMS).**

Using architecture components (Room, ViewModel and LiveData), how can I perform a transaction that saves multiple related entities in the database? The following code currently resides in the ViewModel and works fine. The problem is I want to put this `AsyncTask` in the repository layer like other simple one-operation queries, but is it OK? Because in that case the repository would be responsible for managing relationships and knowing about entity details.

As I said above, the main problem is that I need id of the inserted entity so I can save it in another entity. If this requirement didn't exist, I would be able to persist each entity one by one in separate `AsyncTask`s in the repository.

**MainViewModel.java:**

```
public void buy(Item item, Store store) {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            long storeId = mRepository.insertStore(store);

            Purchase purchase = new Purchase(storeId); // here uses id of the store
            long purchaseId = mRepository.insertPurchase(purchase);

            item.setPurchaseId(purchaseId); // here uses id of the purchase
            mRepository.updateItem(item);

            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're doing is fine if you keep this in the Repository layer. I don't think keeping this in the ViewModel is a good idea as it's suppose to be the Repository's responsibility to handle your data, in this case, the `Item` and `Store` objects. I believe that your Repository should be responsible for the management of this data and its relationships. To answer your question about receiving the ID of the updated entity, what you can do is have your AsyncTask implement the `onPostExecute` method and have your `doInBackground` method return an actual value (like the `storeId`) instead of `null`. You can then have `onPostExecute` retrieve that value and delegate control to a callback listener of some sort.

Comment: But as far as I know `Repository` should be responsible only for deciding **from which source to get or send data (e.g. local database or cloud)** not how to store the data or how entities are related. If anything, the `ViewModel` is the place to handle entity relationships.

Comment: You are right, you should create `UseCaseClass` which wiil implement `Repository` and hold all logic that you need. In your `ViewModel` you should implement this `UseCaseClass` and use it. I have no idea why You're still using `AsyncTask` ;/

Answer (score 0):

You can execute multiple database operations in a transaction using Android Room.
This way, you are ensured that your database integrity is not altered in case one of those operation fails (operations are rolled-back).

Here is how you can define a Transaction with Room in the `Dao` class:

```
@Dao
public abstract class MyDao {

    @Insert
    public abstract long insertStore(Store store);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ROLLBACK)
    public abstract long recordPurchase(Purchase purchase);

    @Update
    public abstract void updateItem(Item updatedItem);

    @Transaction
    public void buyItemFromStore(Item boughtItem, Store store) {
        // Anything inside this method runs in a single transaction.
        long storedId = insertStore(store);

        Purchase purchase = new Purchase(storeId);
        long purchaseId = recordPurchase(purchase);

        item.setPurchaseId(purchaseId);
        updateItem(item);
    }
}
```

You can refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Transaction) for an explanation on how `@Transaction` works.

Then in your repository class, call the `buyItemFromStore` from your `AsyncTask`:

```
public class MyRepository {
    private MyDao dao;

    public void buy(Item item, Store store) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doOnBackground(Void... voids) {
                // Everything is saved in a transaction.
                dao.buyItemFromStore(item, store);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is perfectly fine for the `Repository` layer to be aware of relationships between entities, as long as the stored objects are related in some way (with Store Purchase and Item it seems to be the case).

If you are unable to alter your `Dao` class, consider [`RoomDatabase.runInTransaction`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.html#runInTransaction(java.lang.Runnable)).